# Flyway runs V0 migration scripts on initial migration

Tags: flyway

I am working on a Spring Boot 2.7 application with an existing Oracle 19c database and is trying to integrate Flyway(v8.5). I have created a migration script named `V0__create_tables.sql`, which is intended to be used for setting up tests in H2 at a later stage, and an empty file `V1__baseline.sql`.

I have configured the following properties in my `application.properties` file:

```sql
spring.flyway.baselineVersion=1
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
```

Despite these settings, when I execute `flyway migrate`, the `V0__create_tables.sql` script is executed instead of recognizing it as the baseline and skipping it. In the console I get `origin=org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate message="Current version of schema "STER": << Empty Schema >>"` and no signs of the baseline version being configured as 1.

I have verified that flyway is responding to changes in the `application.properties` file by toggling flyway on and off with `spring.flyway.enable`

Can anyone please help me understand why Flyway is executing the `V0__create_tables.sql` script instead of treating it as the baseline version and skipping it?

Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already have anything in your database when you run these?

If you do not, neither of these will do anything with a default set up of Spring Boot with Flyway.

`baselineOnMigrate` will only run the `baseline` command if there is already (and only) non-Flyway data in your schema. If your database schema is empty, or non-existent, then Flyway will have nothing to baseline and not run the command.
As a result, if `baseline` is not called then `baselineVersion` is not used.

By default, Spring Boot is only running Flyway's `migrate` command. If you need Flyway to run `baseline` on an empty setup then you will need to change the Spring behavior by creating a `FlywayMigrationStrategy` bean which runs `baseline` then `migrate`.

Something like:

```
@Configuration
public class BaselineMigrationStrategyConfig {

    @Bean
    public FlywayMigrationStrategy flywayMigrationStrategy() {
        return flyway -> {
            flyway.baseline();
            flyway.migrate();
        };
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.